# Maxwell equations and aether

Tags: physics, relativity-theory, maxwell

Were Maxwells equations (in their usual common form) assumed to be valid only in ether frame,in the past? If someone would ask them "In what frame are you writing these equations " ,what would they say?

If that is true they assumed that the equations were in ether frame then how come they assumed this?
Knowing that the constituent equations that make up the Maxwell equations were experimentally proved on the earth, which was known to be moving with respect to the ether?

Comment: They would say "in the frame where the aether is at rest". Since the Earth moves through the aether, it was proposed to measure this speed. And the experiment failed. Showing that our mechanics (in fact kinematics!) is not exact.